# Guzzle Pool Async Requests Scope

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using the following code to make concurrent requests with Guzzle for PHP:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Pool;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$client = new Client();

$myvar = 12345;

$requests = function ($total) {
    $uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8126/guzzle-server/perf';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        yield new Request('GET', $uri);
    }
};

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(100), [
    'concurrency' => 5,
    'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) {
        // this is delivered each successful response
        var_dump($myvar);
    },
    'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) {
        // this is delivered each failed request
    },
]);

// Initiate the transfers and create a promise
$promise = $pool->promise();

// Force the pool of requests to complete.
$promise->wait();
```

How would one access data in the 'fulfilled' handler section outside of the scope of the function? The code shown displays NULL, indicating no access to the $myvar variable.

Answer (score 6):

[`use` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) will help you.

```
'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) use ($myvar) {
    // this is delivered each successful response
    var_dump($myvar);
},
```

Comment: Can I set value of `$myvar` in closure function and access outside of it ? if not, then how ?

Comment: @DineshSuthar, you can use it by reference, then all the changes will be reflected outside of the closure. Like `use (&$myvar) {`.